# How to paste clipboard content to specific location in word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

As part to extract data form web I use following (problematic) code.

```
Sub USPTOAbstHTML1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, Tbl As table, StrTxt As String, HttpReq As Object, i As Long, oHtml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ActiveDocument.Range
    For Each Tbl In .Tables
        With Tbl
            For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
                With .Cell(i, 2).Range
                            If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                            MsgBox .Hyperlinks(1).Address
                                HttpReq.Open "GET", .Hyperlinks(1).Address, False
                                HttpReq.send
                                oHtml.body.innerHTML = HttpReq.responseText
                                MsgBox HttpReq.responseText
                                StrTxt = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("claim").Item.innerHTML
                                With IE
                                    .Visible = False
                                    .navigate "about:blank"
                                    .Document.body.innerHTML = StrTxt
                                    .Document.execCommand "SelectAll"
                                    .Document.execCommand "Copy"
                                End With
                                With Tbl.Cell(i, 5).Range
                                   Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
                                End With
                            End If
                            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                            .Find.Execute
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next
End With
Set HttpReq = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem in above code is, I could not find any method by which i could add clipboard content to specific location i.e. Tbl.Cell(i, 5).Range
The code is inserting data wherever selection is.

I tried MSForms.DataObject but I could only found examples with only text whereas my clipboard content is more than just text. (Formatted text with images)

is there any other way I can get the job done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range object also has the Paste, PasteFormat and similar methods. It's possible that you might first need to collapse the range so that it's inside the cell (rather than containing the cell). For example:

```
Set rng = Tbl.Cell(i, 5).Range
rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
rng.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
```